# How to fetch map tiles on GeoServer from Leaflet?

Tags: dictionary, gis, leaflet, geoserver, maptiler

I'm trying to fetch map tiles on GeoServer from Leaflet by using TileLayer, but I can't figure out how to do it.

That is, by writing the following line in a script.

L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/.../{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

For example, if one wants to fetch map tiles of "nyc_roads.zip" (nyc_roads.shp, nyc_roads.shx, nyc_roads.dbf, nyc_roads.prj) from Leaflet, what should one do?

I've made workspace for "nyc_roads" on GeoServer, and it can be seen by OpenLayers. But how to configure GeoServer in order to fetch map tiles from Leaflet? And what is "L.tileLayer(...)" going be?

I'd appreciate whatever you could inform me. Thank you.

Comment: this might help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64406/getting-wfs-data-from-geoserver-into-leaflet